# Стилизация preference settings

Tags: android

Мне нужно сделать страницу настроек, для этого вроде есть родной инструмент в android, много всяких нужных фичей, что в разы ускоряет разработку таких страниц. Но я столкнулся с проблемой стилизации такой страницы, поменять фон, убрать отступы и д.р мелочь, почему с этим (стилизаций) так плохо в android, уже не первый раз сталкиваюсь с ней.
Например, что бы поменять стиль preferenceCategory приходится создавать свой layout, может есть способы как проще это сделать?

Comment: как бы в этом и задумка, сделать настройки во всей системе одинаковыми